# generically detect masked input in a web page

Tags: html

I am wondering if there is a way to generically detect a masked input field (like a password edit box) on a web page.

Comment: In other words, you want to detect all `input type="password"` elements? If so, using what (Javascript maybe?) and based on what kind of source (current HTML DOM?) ?

Comment: yes it is possible, like BalusC says just go trough dom and look for all inputs type password

Answer (score 0):

I you're using jQuery, you can collect all of the password elements on page using a selector:

`$(':password')` or  `$('[type=password]')`

This will return a collection of all elements on the entire page. You could reduce this to just inside a specific element by adding to the selector, eg.:

`$('#mainContent :password')`

This would return all password fields within an element with the ID "mainContent".